# detecting href portal number in href link

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I have a script that detects all `<a>` tags that end in what portal number I picked. in this case it's portal "19" and it adds a target Blank to those links.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('a[href$="portalid=19"]').prop('target', '_blank');
});
```

having trouble having javascript detect the link and grab the number of the portal it's on.

```
href="/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=szYeQD8fY2E%3d&amp;tabid=3988&amp;portalid=19"
```

depending on which portal it's on having it detect the portal number and place that number in the script.

```
var i = portalid
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a[href$="portalid=[i]"]').prop('target', '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the string in your jQuery selector:

```
$('a[href$="portalid=' + i + '"]').prop('target', '_blank');
```